# Whats the point of increasing flashlight accuracy?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

So there is an addon for flashlights that increase the accuracy but what’s the point of increasing the accuracy of the flashlight? Does it blind faster? Or is it just worthless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the accuracy reduces the amount the flashlight beam moves while you’re moving. The flashlight beam already barely moves while you’re moving making them pretty worthless.

Answer (score 0):

It does what it says and increases the accuracy.

This means that you don't have to be as precise with your aim in order to blind the killer. You can afford to be a little bit off target and it will still work.